# Saving a PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, upload

I have a problem with saving PDF files to folders on my server. The code worked at one time and now it doesn't. What I want it to do is to check if someone is trying to upload a PDF when a form is submitted, and if there is a PDF in the file field it uploads it and then saves the path to the mysql database. Code is below:

```
    if (!empty($_FILES['pdf'])){
          $idir = "../files/PDF/"; //my directory file is supposed to be saved in
          $randomd=rand(0000000,9999999); //creates a random number as filename
          $domain = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];  
          $file_ext = strrchr($_FILES['pdf']['name'], '.'); grabs file extension. my code checked if the file was a pdf a different way and neither seems to work.
          $destination=$randomd.$file_ext; //new filename
          if ($file_ext=='pdf') {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], "$idir" . $destination);
                $pdf= $domain."/files/PDF/".$destination;                                             } else { echo("File type not supported.");  
mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_listings SET pdf='$pdf' WHERE listing_id='$lid'");
                                                                            }
```

The if not empty does not work and it always tries to upload a file, but when I check the folder nothing is in there and it doesnt update the mysql.

Comment: What does `move_uploaded_file()` return?

Comment: This function returns either TRUE or FALSE (in some cases it issues warnings). Please refer to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). I think the reason could be writing permissions or file size. Also try using absolute destination path.

Comment: @yuvin after pulling my hair out I found out it was a simple little mistake, which is what I suspected. It should have said  if ($file_ext=='.pdf') {
I forgot one little period!!!

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['pdf']` will never be empty(when the form has been submitted), no matter if a file has been selected or not, it will always return an array.

Check `$_FILES['pdf']['error']` , it will be `4` when no file has been uploaded.